# What jQuery was exposed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is exposed via:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

But there are two jQuery:

```
var jQuery = (function() {

// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    },
```

i understand that it's legitimate names - they're from different scope.
But which one was exposed? 
i suppose it's `var jQuery = function( selector, context )` but it seems it's in different scope from  `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're looking at [`src/core.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) and [`src/outro.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/outro.js).

At the top of `core.js`, there is this code (as shown in your question):

```
var jQuery = (function() {

// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
```

That, on its own, might look like it's assigning a new function to `jQuery`. However, if you look at the bottom:

```
return jQuery;

})();
```

It's executing a function that it just created, and setting `jQuery` to the result (which is the `jQuery` from inside the function).

Then, in `outro.js`, there is this code:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

`jQuery` here is the `jQuery` from the top of `core.js`. Thus, through a series of steps, it is setting `window.jQuery` (as well as `window.$`) to the `jQuery` object defined like this:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    },
```

Comment: Thanks!! That makes sense! i was actually looking at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js